# Manga where MC is forced to learn different skill from different masters then went to school to find a wife and new disciple for his masters

Tags: story-identification, manga

If I remember correctly, the MC also knows how to fix a car, and his masters were almost god-level master, some of his skills includes swordsmanship, crafting, healing, and many more.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

I think its called ["The Max Level Hero Has Returned"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/56358488-the-max-level-hero-has-returned-vol-1).
The main character is "killed" by his step brother for political reasons. He then gets transported to the Mount Olympus where lot of heros are, like Hercules. He then trains there for 1000 years. When he gets back to his world he is very powerful.

Plot description kept vague to avoid spoilers.